# How do I use methods from an object instantiated in a different class?

Tags: java, swing, object, methods

Basically I have a method in my Gui class that prints and appends text and I need to use that method in other classes like my Player class. How do I use that method? If I were to make another Gui object in the player class it would create another JPanel which would be bad right? If I need to move that method to another class be my guest to suggest that. Thanks guys!

Comment: Yes, creating another GUI object would be a bad idea since it would not be the same object as the GUI that is displayed. Much better is StriplingWarrier's suggestion (1+) as this gives you a reference to the current visualized GUI object.

Comment: actually, no - you don't _need_ to use that method, it's your design decision. Which is bad, btw, as it couples the view class into the data class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `Player` class needs to call methods on the `GUI` class, why not have the `Player` class take the `GUI` instance as a constructor argument? So whatever code creates the `Player` will have to tell it what `GUI` it should use for such method calls.

This is an approach known as dependency injection, and is generally considered to be superior to singletons or static methods.

Comment: Here's one of the well-known articles about dependency injection: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html